# How to replace Pipe with a new line in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, scripting

Please, accept my apologies, if this question was asked before. I am new and do not know how to do it. I have a file containing the data like this:

```
name=1|surname=2|phone=3|email=4
phone=5|surname=6|name=7|email=8
surname=9|phone=10|email=11|name=12
phone=13|email=14|name=15|surname=6
```

I would like to have a file like this:

```
name=1
name=7
name=12
name=15
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "cat infile | sed 's#|#\n#g' > outfile" should do the trick.

Comment: Can you please explain this part? sed 's#|#\n#g'

Comment: `cat infile | sed 's#|#\n#g' > outfile` should do the trick.

sed, short for "stream editor", processes the contents of infile and redirects the output into outfile. The `s#A#B#g` command substitues occurrences of A with B; the `g` at the end signifies global substitution (i.e. every occurrence of A is substituted by B).
So, this command substitutes every occurrence of "|" in infile by a newline ("\n") and writes the result into outfile.

Answer (score 2):

Say names.txt is your file, then use something like :

```
cat names.txt  | tr "|" "\n" | grep "^name="
```

- `tr`  transforms `|` to newlines
- `grep` filters for the lines with name

And here is a one command solution with GNU awk:

```
 awk -v RS="[|\n]" '/^name=/' names.txt
```

- the `-v RS="[|\n]' set the record separatro to`|`  or newline
- the `/^name=/` filters for records starting with `name=` (and implicitly prints them)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the solution of @Lars, but I wanted to test this with "lookbehind".
With `grep` you can get the matches only with `grep -o`, but the following line will also find surname:

```
grep -o "name=[0-9]*" names.txt
```

You can fix this a little by looking for the character before name (start of line with `^` or `|`).

```
grep -o "(^|\|)name=[0-9]*" names.txt
```

What a fix! Now you get the right names, but sometimes with an extra `|`.
With \K (and grep option -P) you can tell grep to use something for the matching but skip it during output.

```
grep -oP "(^|\|)\Kname=[0-9]*" names.txt
```